# running apps in compatability mode on windows phone 10

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

Is it possible to run applications in Windows Phone 10 in compatability mode like you can on the desktop? I have an application that runs on Windows Phone 8.1 but users have problems when running in Windows 10 mobile.

The underlying problem is outlined here [Phonegap IndexedDb not commiting data in Windows Phone 10 on larger databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792592/phonegap-indexeddb-not-commiting-data-in-windows-phone-10-on-larger-databases) but I was wondering if a fix would be availble in the settings somewhere.

Comment: there is no such thing under Win10 mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such concept like "Compatibility Mode" in Windows 10 Mobile. There are different emulators and devices available. Each device and emulator can run particular version of Windows Phone/mobile OS. Windows Phone provides with backward compatibility so you can run Windows Phone 8.1 app on Windows 10 mobile and test that functionality which is misbehaving or not working.